# how to populate only complete data with easy catalog

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge, microsoft-excel

I am working with Easy Catalog by 65bit for the first time. Right now I am merging data by setting up field markers. I have included a screen shot of an Excel spreadsheet for reference purposes.

I am populating data tables currently. The issue I am having is figuring out how to populate column headers and its respective data only when it is set. See the screen shot below. When a data record (a row) has a cell that is NULL, then the column header should not appear.

In the second screenshot, you will see how I have an area with A[cm2], m[kg/m], etc. This is the area where the column headers will go. The next row down in my InDesign template is the data associated with the product.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have many options. The one that suits you depends on your layout expectations.

1. Using Conditional Processing in text : 
   @@if {checkLength} = ‘‘@@A@@else@@B@@endif@@
   Would require a custom field (GROUPLIST) to check if group is empty or not
2. Using actions (see pagination rules) to hide text frame if group records are empty. Would still require a custom field thouch
3. Using tables and column removal options to clear column if no rows are filled.
4. Crossed Data table : to generate your own table based on html syntax.

Etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. A few questions about these options. Where would we put the if statements? Also, what would be the best option for minimal production work in the future.

Comment: Conditional processing is all about text. So you need to set the type text cursor inside a text frame and enter the conditional syntax. For your second question, it's a bit more complicated because there isn't a better solution by itself. Cross data table is complex to set yet powerful. Actions work fine generally but you may forget one has been set if you don't look at the pagination rules panel. Conditional Processing works fine too but sometimes the length of the syntax make it difficult to use.